# SQL Server 2017 - copy entire DB to another server on an ongoing basis via a script

Tags: sql-server

I need to copy an entire DB from 1 server to another on a daily/scheduled basis.
Can't use replication - can't add GUIDs to the DB (Source DB - is based on a going  restore).

How can I write a script to copy the entire DB + logins etc to another server.
I can drop the destination DB if needed each time.

Any ideas on a script?

thanks in advance!

Comment: if you DB is not huge, you can perform a `backup and restore`. Also depends on your scenario, Other alternative are `Database Mirroring`, `Log Shipping`. Just read up on this in Microsoft site

Comment: Looking for an SP that will do all that between servers

Comment: To get an SP to copy a backup between servers you need to enable `xp_cmdshell` which is usually a nono. How big is the database? Do you have an existing nightly backup? You're better off adding the backup file push and restore as a step when your nightly backup is finished. Why are you looking for an SP to do this? You don't have enough detail in your question. We're just going to play cat and mouse where we suggest something and you feed us constraints. Please state all the constraints and requirements in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Because you need to also copy any logins across as well, I would look at doing this with the [dbatools PowerShell module](https://dbatools.io/commands/)

Check out the Copy-DbaDatabase and Copy-DbaLogin cmdlets